# QT5.10 and Android openssl

Tags: android, c++, qt, email, ssl

i use QT5.10 and the smtp example Raivis Strogonovs.

on the normal Ubuntu can I send Email correctly.
But under Android I can not send Email, because the SSL is not working.

This is the output from me application:

```
libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_free
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CONF_get1_default_config_file
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_curve_nist2nid
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CipherFinal
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_ctrl
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_ctrl
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_get_builtin_curves
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function EC_get_builtin_curves
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function EC_get_builtin_curves
D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I art     : [ThreadList] before LoadRelaxed()
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:66 (void Smtp::stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)): stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState
D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=smtp.gmail.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
D libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
D libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: smtp.gmail.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:66 (void Smtp::stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)): stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:66 (void Smtp::stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)): stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_ctrl
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_ctrl
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_ctrl
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_ctrl
W libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: (null):0 ((null)): qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_ctrl
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:83 (void Smtp::connected()): Connected
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/fileHandler/fileHandler.cpp:38 (void fileHandler::readFile()): Read in File
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/fileHandler/fileHandler.cpp:52 (void fileHandler::readFile()): "Hello World"
D OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:16(1040:); file:external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c ;Line:610;Function:ssl3_read_bytes
D OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:16(154:); file:external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c ;Line:764;Function:ssl3_get_server_hello
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:71 (void Smtp::errorReceived(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)): error  QAbstractSocket::SocketError(13)
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:66 (void Smtp::stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)): stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:77 (void Smtp::disconnected()): disconneted
D libSporthopaedieRosenbach.so: ../SporthopaedieRosenbach/Smtp/smtp.cpp:78 (void Smtp::disconnected()): error  "Error during SSL handshake: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE, error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO"
```

Comment: have you linked the ssl version for android?

Comment: no, how can I do this

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT + OpenSSL + Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147714/qt-openssl-android)