# How to get libssl.so and libcrypto.so from apk

Tags: android, qt, openssl

So i am try to build openSSL into my qt android app. and to all my efforts from using precompiled binary to installing ubuntu 18 and still failing i am getting desperate.

I have read from this thread:

[QT + OpenSSL + Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147714/qt-openssl-android)

that i can get them from ANY existing apk, so how do i extract it from the apk? Because i do not find it in the android ndk and sdk. if its only selected apk, what program do i use indor for me to see it.

im using Qt 5.11 on windows, but i have linux OS too if needed :) Thank you!

Comment: The apk file is just a zip file with a different extension. It's a bad idea to take libs from here and there. Just build the libs yourself. You can't use a library compiled for x86 on android. Different architectures, different machine code.

Comment: im really having a hard time building the libs, if you you have personally tried it and willing to help me, i am very eager to listen sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built OpenSSL for android a few months ago, with zero issues. Just follow this guide for Linux:

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT="/home/dev/android-ndk-r12b"
SR="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-16/arch-arm"
BR="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-"


RANLIB="$BR"ranlib CC="$BR"gcc ./Configure android-armeabi --prefix=$SR/usr --sysroot=$SR
ANDROID_DEV=$SR/usr make
make install
```

Obviously, you will have to replace the paths with your own depending on where and what NDK version you install, and you will already have downloaded and extracted the OpenSSL source. Also, keep in mind that Qt doesn't seem to work with the latest and "greatest" android toolchains. In fact, android has already switched to llvm, but for Qt you will need to use the older gcc toolchains.

You can use [this script](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-lite-libcrypto/blob/master/build-android.sh) to build libcrypto.

There are many prebuilt binaries you can get online, without having to rummage about in apk files, for example [this repo](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-lite-libcrypto) has openssl libcrypto for a bunch of platforms, including android.

Don't know where you got the idea that you could get the libs from **any** apk file, obviously, it has to be a package from an application that incorporates those libraries for dynamic linking.

Last but not least, if you still plan on getting pre-compiled binaries, keep in mind they have to be built with a version that is compatible with your compiler. Which is why it is best to build the libs yourself, with the same toolchain you are using for your application. There is also the danger of getting "bad" libs from an unknown source, they might be outdated or tampered with.

Comment: the files in the repo for building the libcrypto seems to be for openSSL 1.0.2j. i will need this exact version right? because ubuntu has already built in v1.1.1, and i have to downgrade it.

Comment: It is not a problem to use different versions unless there is some broken or previously unavailable functionality. As long as the stuff you need is available in both versions, you are good. Note that the repo contains not only build scripts but the actual libraries. They are static libs tho.

Comment: Will try sir, i am going first to reinstall ubuntu on vm to start fresh. it seems i messed some files up

Comment: Sorry took me so long to get back to you sir, ./Congifure is cause and error saying `bash ./Configure: no such file or directory. I have check if the path exist it would seems sir that missed a few letters, may ask again what file is `BR` ?

Comment: the file BR is incomplete sir, may i know which one because it would seem there are quite a few with the same starting name

Comment: You just pick the toolchain you want to use, `BR` is a variable that refers to the path of the toolchain. `Configure` is in the folder where you extract the source code.

Comment: oh im sorry so it is correct, now that leaves the ./configure, may i know what source code you are reffering to sir?

Comment: i have also been having trouble on ./configure even with the past guides, i dont know where this folder is

Comment: Update. Here is what i did, I download openSSL v1.0.2q from their site, extracted it  and ran your code there, i then downloaded the copy of the github repo you provided for libcrypto. I ran build-android.sh, it showed me 2 errors `FIPS_SIG does not specify incore module` and line 86 ./configure no file such file in the directory`, im going to edit line 86 to openssl folder configure path

Comment: I have same issue with `./Configure`: `CROSS COMPILE ENV : arm-linux-androideabi-
./build-android.sh: line 86: ./Configure: No such file or directory`

What is the `Configure`?

Answer (score 0):

You can open them by simply changing their extension to ".zip" :) will update if i can find apps that has these files.

PS: No all apk has libcrypto.so and libssl.so.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21531691)

Comment: i am the author, it was supposed to be the answer the question, but it seems stack overflow need 2 more days before i can answer my own question. so it automatically did this. :)